# How to display value from PHP objects and array

Tags: php, arrays, object

How to get value from this object. Actually I would like to display all value ( Ex: id, item etc ) using a loop.

[image]http://prntscr.com/siu120

Comment: you can simply use a `foreach` loop to display the values

Comment: Thank you :)
Problem solved!


      foreach( $eRes as $res ){
    foreach( $res as $re ){
        echo $re->item. '<br>';
    }
 }

Comment: How to get single item by key without loop?
I would like to show 1st array ID as like echo $eRes[0]->id;